# How to inherit django models just for overriding functions?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project where I need to define some models which have some functions with business logic in them, for example how to process the data when fetching from db.

I want to inherit multiple models from the same parent model in where in each model I override some particular functions. I don't want that a new table is made for each new model, since I am only overriding functionality and not adding any fields. How to achieve this?

Proxy models don't help since I can't retrieve the appropriate class from the database object.

Example:-

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    f1=fields.IntegerField()

    def processing_func1(self):
         <default func1 functionality>

    def processing_func2(self):
         <default func2 functionality>

class ChildModel1(models.Model):

    def processing_func1(self):
         <overridden func1 functionality>

class ChildModel2(models.Model):

    def processing_func2(self):
         <overridden func2 functionality>
```

I need child models to be accessible via the ParentModel. For example, if I do ParentModel.objects.all() I get objects of ChildModels. For normal model inheritance, I am achieving that using django-model-utils.

Comment: What do you mean by `can't retrieve the appropriate class from the database object`? If you define ChildModels as proxies you'll be able to work with database as it is parent model. Proxy models are needed exactly for your case.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: I need child models to be accessible via the ParentModel. For example, if I do ParentModel.objects.all() I get objects of ChildModels. For normal model inheritance, I am achieving that using django-model-utils by saying ParentModel.object.select_subclasses()

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Mixin here and make abstract classes inherits the properties from django models

Something like this.

```
class UtilMixin(models.Model):

    def processing_func1(self):
         <default func1 functionality>

    def processing_func2(self):
         <default func2 functionality>

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ChildModel1(UtilMixin):

    def processing_func1(self):
         <overridden func1 functionality>

class ChildModel2(UtilMixin):

    def processing_func2(self):
         <overridden func2 functionality>
```

Comment: This still makes a new table for each of my new class.

Comment: Oh sorry my answer is partly relevance for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). As described in the document:

> When using multi-table inheritance, a new database table is created
> for each subclass of a model. This is usually the desired behavior,
> since the subclass needs a place to store any additional data fields
> that are not present on the base class. Sometimes, however, you only
> want to change the Python behavior of a model – perhaps to change the
> default manager, or add a new method.

so you can add or override functions by creating a *proxy* for the original model.
Here is an example of how to create a **proxy model**:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```

The `MyPerson` class operates on the same database table as its parent `Person` class. In particular, any new instances of `Person` will also be accessible through `MyPerson`.